# How would I Interpolate a decimated image by a factor of 2 using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[Problem Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vH9O.png)

I have the following code for the decimation horizantally for example, how would I represent Interpolate version for the image that is decimated?

```
shirtimage=imread('shirtimage.png');
figure
imshow(shirtimage);
axis on
filterhor = [0.25,0.5,0.25];
filteredhor = imfilter(shirtimage,filterhor);
decimatedhor = filteredhor(:,1:2:end);
imshow(decimatedhor)
title('Image with horizantal filtering')
axis on
```

[Shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNih2.jpg)

Comment: The answer to your question is: using a multidimensional array. But perhaps that is not exactly the question you would like to ask.

Comment: how do i use a multidimensional array? my professor said I can't use the Interpolate function itself in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of interpolation that can be used to upscale the decimated image back to its original size. One method is the nearest neighbour method (pixel replication).

Some other methods include:

• Bilinear interpolation → less jaggies/staircasing

• Bicubic interpolation → less jaggies/staircasing

[image: Nearest Neighbour Interpolation]

[image: Horizontally Interpolated Image]

```
shirtimage = imread('shirtimage.png');

close all;
Decimation_Factor = 2;
Horizontal_Decimated_Image = shirtimage(:,1:Decimation_Factor:end);


subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Horizontal_Decimated_Image);
title('Horizontally Decimated Image');

%Interpolating image to obtain the a predicted original image%

%Using replication%
[Original_Image_Height,Original_Image_Width] = size(shirtimage);
[Decimated_Image_Height,Decimated_Image_Width] = size(Horizontal_Decimated_Image);


%Interpolation factors%
X_Scaling_Factor = Original_Image_Width/Decimated_Image_Width;
Y_Scaling_Factor = Original_Image_Height/Decimated_Image_Height;


Interpolated_Image = zeros(Original_Image_Height,Original_Image_Width);


for y = 1: +1: Original_Image_Height
   for x = 1: +1: Original_Image_Width 
 
%The coordinate attempting to be determined from the decimated image%
Coordinate_X_From_Decimated_Image = floor(x/X_Scaling_Factor);
Coordinate_Y_From_Decimated_Image = floor(y/Y_Scaling_Factor);

if(Coordinate_Y_From_Decimated_Image < 1)
Coordinate_Y_From_Decimated_Image = 1;
end

if(Coordinate_X_From_Decimated_Image < 1)
Coordinate_X_From_Decimated_Image = 1;
end

Interpolated_Image(y,x) = Horizontal_Decimated_Image(Coordinate_Y_From_Decimated_Image,Coordinate_X_From_Decimated_Image);
       
   end 
end


Filter = [0.25,0.5,0.25];
Filtered_Image = imfilter(Interpolated_Image,Horizontal_Filter);


subplot(1,2,2); imshow(uint8(Filtered_Image));
title('Recovered/Interpolated Image');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would this be the simplest way to perform interpolation with out using the function it self?

Comment: Yes, nearest neighbour interpolation is the simplest approach that I know of. Is fidelity/image quality of concern in this question?

Comment: No, I was just curious to see if there are easier ways to do it because doing the decimation was easier

Comment: To recover the image interpolation is required to upscale the image back to the original size. Note typically filtering is applied after interpolation to remove jagged edges.

Comment: If I wanted to do it vertically , would it be the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same. Decimation can be done in both directions then interpolation can be applied the same way to recover the image.

Comment: The script above should still work if you choose to decimate the image in both directions before interpolating. Decimation and filtering are usually done in both directions in most practical use cases.

Comment: Great! that helps, also thank you for providing the box to make me understand the difference. Let say the factor was 1.5 instead of 2, would the two decimated and interpolation box representation be the same ?

Comment: Typically interpolation/upscaling and decimation are done using an integer, whole number. But say the factor is 3 for example the diagram would have more replications to fill in the missing pixels required to scale the image up.

Comment: Here is a resource that can help with any further understanding. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqscP7rc8_M Hope all this helps. Good luck with all your studies.